# Return string from function typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am having issues returning a string instead of a function in an object value.
Currently an arrow function returns an array of objects, and one of those needs to conditionally change a value based on the value passed in.
Here's the code:

```
const requestOptions = () => [
{
     id: 3,
     label: (object: Object) => `${activeStatus(object)}`,
     value: 'toggleActiveStatus',
}]
```

The activeStatus method returns a string, but really struggling to get label to be assigned a string instead of type *(validationRule: ValidationRule) => string*. *requestOptions* gets invoked to return the options as prop for a component.

I have tried a number of variations of

```
label: (object: Object) => string = () => {
```

and invoking the function as an IIFE.

Any ideas on how I could get it to return the string itself, not the function?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's `object`?

Comment: It's the object from which I want a value to set the label. For example object.status could be active or inactive, and method returns a string based on that value.

Comment: Yeah but where does it come from? How do you plan to pass the `object` parameter?

Comment: requestOptions gets passed into a table, and in one of the rows is passed as an options prop for a dropdown. 
So I have other dropdowns which have actions : 
```
{
      id: 2,
      label: 'Clone',
      value: 'cloneRule',
      action: (object: Object) => cloneRule(object),
    },
```
which work fine and can read the object

Comment: But these are functions and so work fine, but I need label to return a string, not a function which returns a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `label` to be a string, then you can simply drop the anonymous function:

```
const requestOptions = () => [
{
     id: 3,
     label: `${activeStatus(object)}`,
     value: 'toggleActiveStatus',
}]
```

Comment: Don't think that works though as the requestOptions function is called in a different component, so needs the function to get the object

Comment: Ah was able to manually pass the object into requestOptions and that fixed it! Thank you both for the help!